# Can I bring DVDs and personal items in checked luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airport-security

I'm going to NZ, and I want to bring my DVDs with as well as some personal items. One of which is a vibrator. Do I need to declare any of them?

Answer (score 3):

In general you can bring personal items as you wish. The caveats are

1. Above a certain monetary value you may have to look at specific customs regulation
2. The items need to be legal in the departure and destination country
3. The items should be legal on all layover/stopover country
4. It's easiest if the items you bring don't violate any cultural or political sensitivities in all countries you touch. It's not necessarily a show stopper, but can add significant hassle to your travels.

Bringing  vibrator into New Zealand is no problem at all. However, having one in your carry on baggage during a layover in certain middle eastern countries may be one. Same goes for DVDs: it really depends on what's the content.

Comment: The DVDs are legally purchased movies like Disney classics and some others like Eragon, Jurassic Park etc I just don't keep them in their original casing